# Max count of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, count, tuples, counter

I have a list of tuples like this :-

```
l = [(1, 2, 'ABC'), (3, 2, 'LLL'), (4, 1, 'kkk')]
```

I want to get the item with having maximum count.Basically I am only comparing the 2nd element in each tuple and counting which occurs max times.

The output for above should be 2 since 2 is the most occurred element in all tuples.

Another example :-

```
a = [ [("l", 4, 'ABC'), ("k", 1, 'LLL'), ("j", 1, 'kkk')]
```

The output for above should be 1 as 1 is the most occurred in all tuples.

How can one do this ?

Comment: What has one tried, and what happened when one did so?

Comment: Counting problems are generally pretty straight forward using dictionaries.  Have you tried anything and had problems with it?  If so, post your code so we can help you.

Comment: I tried playing with Counter from collections but couldn't get it to work for my data type.
Counter(a).most_common(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Counter` and `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

l = [(1, 2, 'ABC'), (3, 2, 'LLL'), (4, 1, 'kkk')]
print(Counter(map(itemgetter(1), l)).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

prints `2`

Comment: Thanks for this. But can you explain the variables used ? What does itemgetter(1) do ? And what values are passing in .most_common(1)[0][0] ?

Comment: @skyfail: Please Google it. You will learn much more things apart from the functions mentioned here

Comment: @skyfail  `itemgetter(n)` is an alternative version for writing `lambda item: item[n]`